# meteor iron-router and getting the names of all routes for the accounts-entry package

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router, middleware

The popular [accounts-entry](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/) package has an iron-router related bug in it. I believe the later versions of iron-router changed to work better as middleware and so a call to `Router.routes`

At line 87 of this [file](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/blob/master/shared/router.coffee#L87) the following code is used:

```
_.each Router.routes, (route)->
  exclusions.push route.name
# Change the fromWhere session variable when you leave a path
Router.onStop ->
  # If the route is an entry route, no need to save it
  if (!_.contains(exclusions, Router.current().route?.getName()))
    Session.set('fromWhere', Router.current().path)
```

Unfortunately it does not seems like doing an _.each on Router.routes is a solution that works anymore because Router.routes does not return and object with .name properties in it.

How would you get the name of all the routes with the latest iron-router?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is a little tricky : in the latest version of `iron:router`, `Router.routes` is now defined as an array of functions.

Thing is, functions already have a default `name` property in JS which contains the name the function was assigned on definition.

```
var myFunc = function funcName(){...};
console.log(myFunc.name); // == "funcName"
```

Fortunately, there is a `getName` method defined on the route items of the array and you can use this piece of code to iterate over all routes and get their name :

```
_.each(Router.routes, function(route){
  console.log(route.getName());
});
```

Comment: ok, so it seems like my original each function would work, I just needed route.getName() instead of route.name... one difficulty I have with the array of functions it returns is figuring out how to use it correctly. Do you know how someone would inspect an instance of the function to see what methods are available within it? E.g. if I do Router.routes[0] it returns the first function, if I do Router.routes[0]() its invalid, so how would I figure out that Router.routes[0].getName() is even possible?

Comment: You could open your browser console and type `for(var prop in Router.routes[0]){console.log(prop);}`, best solution I could come up under a minute.

Comment: ah, beautiful, one day I might not have to ask dumb questions, but for now, much appreciated