# Find all routes defined in Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Is there a way to add a site map dynamically for all paths which are defined in the Iron Router Router?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each paths}}
        <li><a href="pathFor {{route}}">{{route}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Also, maybe corresponding sub-paths which will be displayed in a child `ul`?

Obviously I could also just create the list manually, but for an app with 50+ links this is quite of a work.

Comment: `Router.routes` is an array of all the paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly!  As Kassym noted, `Router.routes` contains a list of all the routes.  However it contains the router *functions*, so you'll have to go and grab their names with [`route.getName()`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router#route-names).  The default route doesn't have a name, so you'll have to grab the `.path()` instead.

The whole thing should look like this in your helper:

```js
Template.allRoutes.helpers({
  paths: function () {
    var allRoutes = _.map(Router.routes, function(route){
      var routeName = typeof route.getName() === 'undefined' ?
                      route.path() :
                      route.getName(); 
      return {route: routeName}
    });
    return allRoutes
  }
});
```

And this in your template:

```html
<template name="allRoutes">
  {{#each paths}}
    <li><a href="{{pathFor route}}">{{route}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

#### [Working Demo in MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ojj9u6M5DhfCo975v/All_Routes)

> **Note**: Remember to enclose `pathFor` in curly brackets because it is a helper method.  It will execute javascript and inherit the current datacontext, so you can pass it any property from the current context.

In order to display an sub paths of *n* depth, you can recursively call your template like this:

```html
<template name="subpaths">
  <ul>
  {{#each subpaths}}
    <li>
      <a href="{{pathFor path}}">{{path}}</a>
      {{#if subpaths}} {{>subpaths}} {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

[Demo in meteor pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/EfkKzDhKzKH4GG7R5/All_Routes_Nesting)

For more info, see [getting the names of all routes for the accounts-entry package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28651428/1366033)

Comment: One question: is this also working for subpaths? What happens in case of -> Articles -> Article 1 -> Detail... Am I right that Articles wont be automatically a drop down, as this has a child nav?

Comment: Any nesting logic you'd like will be left as an exercise to the reader.  But you certainly have enough information here to do the transformation in JavaScript and add an additional `{{#each}}` block to the template.  If you get stuck along the way, come back and ask a specific question with the code you're trying and what's not working about it. Best Luck!

Comment: don't get me wrong, thank you for your help, but I think it doesn't work with this approach, does it? Because even if you implement another each block, what about sub-sub navis? <ul><li><ul><li><ul></ul></li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: I know this site from a few years now and I know it's not for writing all of the solution. But what you provided was what I already could do, I was asking specifically about the sub navs, too. The solution you provided in your comment now, about template recursion, is what I was looking for. I didn't think about that. If you would update your answer to also provide this information then I will accept it as answered.

Comment: @FrederikWitte, thanks.  My one future ask is if you could already do everything from the current answer, then you should include some of that (*working*) code in your question, which was still a pretty far way off.  It forced me to duplicate work you had already done, and didn't highlight what the actual issue was.  I'll update my answer (also - see the hint above from yesterday that included template recursion)